# How to adjust JTable columns to fit the longest content in column cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jgoodies, tablecolumn

I'm using answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5820366 and http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/ and it works, but frequently columns' sizes are too wide or too narrow.

No matter filling my table with HTML or text.

Using standard `TableModel` from oracle documentation.

Resize mode = JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF

Container of my tabel is jGoodies:

```
FormLayout currentEventLayout = new FormLayout(
            "fill:p",
            "pref, pref");
PanelBuilder currentEventBuilder = new PanelBuilder(currentEventLayout);
currentEventBuilder.add(mainQuotesTable.getTableHeader(), constraints.xy(1, 1));
currentEventBuilder.add(mainQuotesTable, constraints.xy(1, 2));
```

HTML example:

```
"<html><pre><font size=+1 face='Arial'>" + firstValue + "\n" + secondValue + "</font></pre></html>"
```

simple row:

```
firstValue + " - " + secondValue
```

Here is the example:

```
public class TableAdjustExample {
private static JTable mainTable;
private static Random random = new Random();

private static List<Data> data;

private static class Data {
    String name;
    String surname;

    private Data(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    data = stubProvider();

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("table adjust example");
    frame.add(createUI());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(350, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    update();
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            update();
        }
    }, 3000, 3000);
}

private static JPanel createUI() {
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    mainTable = new JTable(2, 3);
    mainTable.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {
        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Data dataItem = data.get(rowIndex);
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                return dataItem.name;
            }
            if (columnIndex == 1) {
                return dataItem.surname;
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    });
    mainTable.setGridColor(Color.black);
    mainTable.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
    mainTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    final TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer = mainTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    mainTable.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object o, boolean b, boolean b1, int row, int column) {
            JLabel parent = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, o, b, b1, row, column);
            if (column == 0) {
                parent.setText("name");
            } else {
                parent.setText("surname");
            }
            return parent;
        }
    });

    jPanel.add(mainTable.getTableHeader());
    jPanel.add(mainTable);

    return jPanel;
}

private static void update() {
    System.out.println("updating");
    data = stubProvider();

    adjustJTableRowSizes(mainTable);
    for (int i = 0; i < mainTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        adjustColumnSizes(mainTable, i, 2);
    }
}

private static void adjustJTableRowSizes(JTable jTable) {
    for (int row = 0; row < jTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
        int maxHeight = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < jTable.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = jTable.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            Object valueAt = jTable.getValueAt(row, column);
            Component tableCellRendererComponent = cellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, valueAt, false, false, row, column);
            int heightPreferable = tableCellRendererComponent.getPreferredSize().height;
            maxHeight = Math.max(heightPreferable, maxHeight);
        }
        jTable.setRowHeight(row, maxHeight);
    }

}

public static void adjustColumnSizes(JTable table, int column, int margin) {
    DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel) table.getColumnModel();
    TableColumn col = colModel.getColumn(column);
    int width;

    TableCellRenderer renderer = col.getHeaderRenderer();
    if (renderer == null) {
        renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    }
    JLabel comp = (JLabel) renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, col.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
    width = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

    for (int r = 0; r < table.getRowCount(); r++) {
        renderer = table.getCellRenderer(r, column);
        comp = (JLabel) renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, table.getValueAt(r, column), false, false, r, column);
        int currentWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
        width = Math.max(width, currentWidth);
    }

    width += 2 * margin;

    col.setPreferredWidth(width);
}

private static List<Data> stubProvider() {
    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        data.add(new Data(
                "<html>" +
                        "<div style='font-size: 15px'>Jason</div>" +
                        "<div style='font-size: 15px'>" + random.nextInt() + "</div>" +
                        "</html>",
                "Statham " + random.nextInt()));
    }
    return data;
}
}
```

---

I have such problem with row height adjustment. Using of `<pre>\n</pre>` instead of `<br>` fixed row adjustment.

Comment: I've also tried using packAll of jxtable but it behaves like jtable - sometimes cuts off the text and sometimes leaves much padding

Comment: You may need to add in the column grid (like1 extra pixel) and/or add in some addition padding. For this to work well, make sure your using a fixed width font.

Comment: what do you mean fixed width font? Im filling the table dynamically and i don't know the width of next content. Also if i use setRowHeight, wrong column width appears more frequently and i can't understand how its related.

Comment: There are two types of `Font`s that the system can use, typically Swing will use fixed width font, which means that each character in the font is the same width, but you can also supply a variable width font, where each character is potentially a different width, which will make it next to near impossible to calculate a reasonable average column width - `Arial` is a variable width font

Comment: Tried. Nope.. still not working

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing ...

Comment: At last posted an example! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems to be working okay for me...

[image]

```
public class TestTable01 extends JPanel {

    private JTable mainTable;

    public TestTable01() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sport",
                                "# of Years",
                                "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
             "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
             "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
             "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
             "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
             "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        mainTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        mainTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        mainTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        mainTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        update();

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainTable);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TestTable01 newContentPane = new TestTable01();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void update() {
        System.out.println("updating");

        adjustJTableRowSizes(mainTable);
        for (int i = 0; i < mainTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            adjustColumnSizes(mainTable, i, 2);
        }
    }

    private void adjustJTableRowSizes(JTable jTable) {
        for (int row = 0; row < jTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
            int maxHeight = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < jTable.getColumnCount(); column++) {
                TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = jTable.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Object valueAt = jTable.getValueAt(row, column);
                Component tableCellRendererComponent = cellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, valueAt, false, false, row, column);
                int heightPreferable = tableCellRendererComponent.getPreferredSize().height;
                maxHeight = Math.max(heightPreferable, maxHeight);
            }
            jTable.setRowHeight(row, maxHeight);
        }

    }

    public void adjustColumnSizes(JTable table, int column, int margin) {
        DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel) table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn col = colModel.getColumn(column);
        int width;

        TableCellRenderer renderer = col.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }
        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, col.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
        width = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

        for (int r = 0; r < table.getRowCount(); r++) {
            renderer = table.getCellRenderer(r, column);
            comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, table.getValueAt(r, column), false, false, r, column);
            int currentWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
            width = Math.max(width, currentWidth);
        }

        width += 2 * margin;

        col.setPreferredWidth(width);
        col.setWidth(width);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**UPDATED**

There are a number of issues with your example.

- Tables really should be added to a `JScrollPane`, this will take care of adding the header...
- The default layout manager for a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, in this case, it's probably not what you want, you probably want to use a `BorderLayout`
- Swing is not thread safe.  The user of `java.util.Timer` will violate this policy, this could cause the model and view to fall out sync.  Use a `javax.swing.Timer` instead.
- Rendering two `<div>` next to each will cause the html layout engine to place a weak break between the elements.  That is, if the engine decides there's not enough available space to render the two elements together, it will split them.  Better to use a single `<div>` with two `<span>` tags instead...

I would have a read of

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

[image]

```
public class TestColumnWidths {

    private static JTable mainTable;
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static List<Data> data;

    private static class Data {

        String name;
        String surname;

        private Data(String name, String surname) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                data = stubProvider();

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("table adjust example");
                frame.add(createUI());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                update();
//                    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
//                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void run() {
//                            update();
//                        }
//                    }, 3000, 3000);

                javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        update();
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(true);
                timer.setCoalesce(true);
                timer.start();

            }
        });
    }

    private static JPanel createUI() {
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        mainTable = new JTable(2, 3);
        mainTable.setModel(new AbstractTableModel() {
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                Data dataItem = data.get(rowIndex);
                if (columnIndex == 0) {
                    return dataItem.name;
                }
                if (columnIndex == 1) {
                    return dataItem.surname;
                }
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        });
        mainTable.setGridColor(Color.black);
        mainTable.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
        mainTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        final TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer = mainTable.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        mainTable.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object o, boolean b, boolean b1, int row, int column) {
                JLabel parent = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, o, b, b1, row, column);
                if (column == 0) {
                    parent.setText("name");
                } else {
                    parent.setText("surname");
                }
                return parent;
            }
        });

//            jPanel.add(mainTable.getTableHeader());
//            jPanel.add(mainTable);

        jPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jPanel.add(new JScrollPane(mainTable));

        return jPanel;
    }

    private static void update() {
        System.out.println("updating");
        data = stubProvider();

        adjustJTableRowSizes(mainTable);
        for (int i = 0; i < mainTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            adjustColumnSizes(mainTable, i, 2);
        }
    }

    private static void adjustJTableRowSizes(JTable jTable) {
        for (int row = 0; row < jTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
            int maxHeight = 0;
            for (int column = 0; column < jTable.getColumnCount(); column++) {
                TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = jTable.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Object valueAt = jTable.getValueAt(row, column);
                Component tableCellRendererComponent = cellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, valueAt, false, false, row, column);
                int heightPreferable = tableCellRendererComponent.getPreferredSize().height;
                maxHeight = Math.max(heightPreferable, maxHeight);
            }
            jTable.setRowHeight(row, maxHeight);
        }

    }

    public static void adjustColumnSizes(JTable table, int column, int margin) {
        DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel) table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn col = colModel.getColumn(column);
        int width;

        TableCellRenderer renderer = col.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }
        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, col.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
        width = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

        for (int r = 0; r < table.getRowCount(); r++) {
            renderer = table.getCellRenderer(r, column);
            comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    table, table.getValueAt(r, column), false, false, r, column);
            int currentWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
            width = Math.max(width, currentWidth);
        }

        width += 2 * margin;

        col.setPreferredWidth(width);
    }

    private static List<Data> stubProvider() {
        List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            data.add(new Data(
                    "<html>"
                    + "<div>"
                    + "<span style='font-size: 15px'>Jason</span>"
                    + "<span style='font-size: 15px'>" + random.nextInt() + "</span>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "</html>",
                    "Statham " + random.nextInt()));
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example i has wrapped update method in timer and on screenshot you can see that second column has inappropriate size http://i45.tinypic.com/359eooj.png  How can I overcome this vicious table :(

Comment: ? What type of timer ? Do you have sample code I can play with ?

Comment: the same i used in my example

Comment: when table filling by the usual string, this bug appears very rarely

Comment: @trickster77777 There are gaps in your knowledge about basic Swing.  I've updated my answer with a working example

Comment: Glad we got that figured out :P

Answer (score 0):

Set reasonable MinimumWidth for the columns which are too narrow. Then calculate width according to the contents of the columns and set them.

Comment: The problem is that `Component` (content of the cell) returns wrong PreferredSize in some conditions. That's why no matter set MinSize or PrefSize. I need to adjust columns after every table update.

Comment: @trickster77777 1) there no issue to get maxSize from String value and apply this value to the last column in the ColumnModel, 2) `returns wrong PreferredSize in some conditions` - for better help sooner post an short, runnable and compilable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)