# JXTable width to adjust according to content

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtable

I have a JXTable that is created like this:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
contentPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
tbl = new JXTable();
tbl.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
tbl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
tbl.setEditable(false);
scrollPane.setViewportView(tbl);
```

The problem is that when it gets filled, all the columns are squashed to fit into the table. I expected the columns to be adjusted according to the width of the column header or column value (which ever is broader) and then for a horizontal scroll bar to be displayed that will enable me to scroll left or right.

How do I  bridge this problem?

Comment: Start by trying to use [`JXTable#setAutoResizeMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode(int)) to `JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF` and then have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013989/how-to-adjust-jtable-columns-to-fit-the-longest-content-in-column-cells/13037771#13037771).  This is a very expensive operation, so beware...

Comment: setHorizontalScrollEnabled(true) did the trick.

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.coderanch.com/t/636348/GUI/java/JXTable-width-adjust-content)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `packAll` method: this resizes columns to fit the viewport; if horizontal scrolling is enabled, columns will get their preferred width.