# How to change JTable column width depending on data?

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

How would I resize the column for it to just fit the largest string in that column. For example in one column I might have a word like "Monday" and I want this column to be shorter than the "Wednesday" column.

The data changes often as it shows the next 3 days, so I would want Java to automatically change it depending on the input data rather than me having to manually set the column width.

My JTable is within a JScrollPane if that changes anything

Hope that makes sense. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: try table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN)

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013989/how-to-adjust-jtable-columns-to-fit-the-longest-content-in-column-cells/13037771#13037771)