# JTable set column width to keep all text

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Okay so I have a jtable in a jscrollpane. Currently the columns are set to a minimum width. If the container is too big for that width to fill the container they get wider. However they will not shrink. To show you what I'm talking about
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjJRN.png)
Here the table has all column headers and cell values visible. The cell width was expanded to fill the container. Upon resizing we get this

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7XdI.png)

Here the columns have been reduced to their minimum width and as the container can not hold them all the scrollbars have been added. In the second image you can see that the header "Vry long title get smushed" and the cell vlaue "Very long cell data" get reduced and replaced with "...". What I would like to do is change this minimum column width for each column to be long enough that it will never cut off whats in the table. This includes both the cell value and the header. I have only been able to find people asking about one or the other and not both. here is my relevant code.

```
co[0] = "Vry long title get smushed";
o[1][1] = "Very long cell data";
JTable table1 = new JTable(o, co)
        {
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
            {
                return getPreferredSize().width < getParent().getWidth();
            }
        };  
    table1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table1.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
    tablePane.setViewportView(table1);
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013989/how-to-adjust-jtable-columns-to-fit-the-longest-content-in-column-cells/13037771#13037771)?  Why this works on the column data, the concept can be applied quite easily for the header as well

Answer (score 1):

Set this property to table

```
setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Use this utility class to autofit columns

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.View;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class AutofitTableColumns {

private static final int DEFAULT_COLUMN_PADDING = 5;

/*
 * @param JTable aTable, the JTable to autoresize the columns on
 * @param boolean includeColumnHeaderWidth, use the Column Header width as a minimum width
 * @returns The table width, just in case the caller wants it...
 */
public static int autoResizeTable(JTable aTable, boolean includeColumnHeaderWidth) {
    return (autoResizeTable(aTable, includeColumnHeaderWidth, DEFAULT_COLUMN_PADDING));
}

/*
 * @param JTable aTable, the JTable to autoresize the columns on
 * @param boolean includeColumnHeaderWidth, use the Column Header width as a minimum width
 * @param int columnPadding, how many extra pixels do you want on the end of each column
 * @returns The table width, just in case the caller wants it...
 */
public static int autoResizeTable(JTable aTable, boolean includeColumnHeaderWidth, int columnPadding) {
    int columnCount = aTable.getColumnCount();
    int tableWidth = 0;

    Dimension cellSpacing = aTable.getIntercellSpacing();

    if (columnCount > 0) // must have columns !
    {
        // STEP ONE : Work out the column widths

        int columnWidth[] = new int[columnCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            columnWidth[i] = getMaxColumnWidth(aTable, i, true, columnPadding);

            tableWidth += columnWidth[i];
        }

        // account for cell spacing too
        tableWidth += ((columnCount - 1) * cellSpacing.width);

        // STEP TWO : Dynamically resize each column

        // try changing the size of the column names area
        JTableHeader tableHeader = aTable.getTableHeader();

        Dimension headerDim = tableHeader.getPreferredSize();

        // headerDim.height = tableHeader.getHeight();
        headerDim.width = tableWidth;
        tableHeader.setPreferredSize(headerDim);

        TableColumnModel tableColumnModel = aTable.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn tableColumn;

        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            tableColumn = tableColumnModel.getColumn(i);

            tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(columnWidth[i]);
        }

    }

    return (tableWidth);
}

/*
 * @param JTable aTable, the JTable to autoresize the columns on
 * @param int columnNo, the column number, starting at zero, to calculate the maximum width on
 * @param boolean includeColumnHeaderWidth, use the Column Header width as a minimum width
 * @param int columnPadding, how many extra pixels do you want on the end of each column
 * @returns The table width, just in case the caller wants it...
 */
public static int getMaxColumnWidth(JTable aTable, int columnNo,
        boolean includeColumnHeaderWidth,
        int columnPadding) {
    TableColumn column = aTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnNo);
    Component comp = null;
    int maxWidth = 0;

    if (includeColumnHeaderWidth) {
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = column.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (headerRenderer != null) {
            comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(aTable, column.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, columnNo);

            if (comp instanceof JTextComponent) {
                JTextComponent jtextComp = (JTextComponent) comp;

                String text = jtextComp.getText();
                Font font = jtextComp.getFont();
                FontMetrics fontMetrics = jtextComp.getFontMetrics(font);

                maxWidth = SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(fontMetrics, text);
            } else {
                maxWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                String headerText = (String) column.getHeaderValue();
                JLabel defaultLabel = new JLabel(headerText);

                //Igor
                //ako je u table modelu kao ime kolone stvalje html code
                //treba izracunati max duzinu text na sljedeci nacin
                View view = (View) defaultLabel.getClientProperty("html");
                if (view != null) {
                    Document d = view.getDocument();
                    if (d instanceof StyledDocument) {
                        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) d;
                        int length = doc.getLength();
                        headerText = StringUtils.leftPad("", length + DEFAULT_COLUMN_PADDING);
                    }
                }
                //END Igor

                Font font = defaultLabel.getFont();
                FontMetrics fontMetrics = defaultLabel.getFontMetrics(font);

                maxWidth = SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(fontMetrics, headerText);
            } catch (ClassCastException ce) {
                // Can't work out the header column width..
                maxWidth = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    TableCellRenderer tableCellRenderer;
    // Component comp;
    int cellWidth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < aTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
        tableCellRenderer = aTable.getCellRenderer(i, columnNo);

        comp = tableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(aTable, aTable.getValueAt(i, columnNo), false, false, i, columnNo);
        //textarea na prvo mjesto jer je takodjer descendant od JTextComponent
        if (comp instanceof JTextArea) {
            JTextComponent jtextComp = (JTextComponent) comp;

            String text = getMaximuWrapedString(jtextComp.getText());
            Font font = jtextComp.getFont();
            FontMetrics fontMetrics = jtextComp.getFontMetrics(font);

            int textWidth = SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(fontMetrics, text);

            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, textWidth);
        } else if (comp instanceof JTextComponent) {
            JTextComponent jtextComp = (JTextComponent) comp;

            String text = jtextComp.getText();
            Font font = jtextComp.getFont();
            FontMetrics fontMetrics = jtextComp.getFontMetrics(font);

            int textWidth = SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(fontMetrics, text);

            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, textWidth);
        } else {
            cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            // maxWidth = Math.max ( headerWidth, cellWidth );
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, cellWidth);
        }
    }

    return (maxWidth + 5 + columnPadding);
}

/**
 * racuna maximalnu duzinu najduzeg stringa wrapped texta
 *
 * @param str
 * @return
 */
private static String getMaximuWrapedString(String str) {
    StringTokenizer strT = new StringTokenizer(str, "\n");
    String max = "";
    String s = "";
    while (strT.hasMoreTokens()) {
        s = strT.nextToken();
        if (s.length() > max.length()) {
            max = s;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

}