# Horizontal scroll limit in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My situation is as such: I've a `JTable`, one of the cells stores a long length of text coming from a database.

I have an horizontal scroll-bar working fine.
But the scroll seems limited and show only 212 chars then displays ...

No error occurs.

Any idea why I can't scroll further to display all the text?

Comment: Either the width of the cell or the size of the label are been limited in same way. *"How do I fix it"* - The fact is, it should work by default.  Try resizing the column

Comment: Maybe you could try something like [How to adjust JTable columns to fit the longest content in column cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013989/how-to-adjust-jtable-columns-to-fit-the-longest-content-in-column-cells/13037771#13037771)

Comment: Can we some code  showing the table construction and example data (you are having trouble with) ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Check out the [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/). It shows basic code to set the column width once the data has been loaded into the table. Or if you choose you can use the supplied class to have the column adjust dynamically as the users enters/changes data in the table.