# How to make a JTable's width >= the enclosing scroll pane's width?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I want to make the table width at least fitting the enclosing scroll pane's width, and if it's getting larger, the horizontal scroll bar is used.

None of `JTable`'s auto resize modes suits my need: `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF` does allow the table to be resized larger than the scroll pane's width, but it can't limit the table's minimal width; the other modes don't allow the table width to be larger than the scroll pane's width at all.

I have tried to set the minimal size as below but it didn't work:

```
JTable table = new JTable(myModel);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

// After the table is displayed.
table.setMinimalSize(scrollPane.getSize());
```

Any idea to achieve that?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014950/jtable-horizontal-scrollbar-based-on-width-of-one-column/15015445#15015445)

Comment: Try `setPreferredSize()` in addition to `setMinimalSize()` most layout managers honor the preferred size rather than the minimum size.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If I use `setPreferredSize()`, the table width will become fixed to the preferred width, and can never be resized again.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Seems that's a different question...

Comment: @ZhaoYi Really?  How?  It will cause the columns to fill the horizontal width of the scroll pane when the total width of the table is smaller then the viewport, but will allow it to over expand (showing the horizontal scroll bars when it's to large)

Comment: Not in my experience. The width is limited by setMaximumWidth() not by the preferred width. But this also depends on the layout manager.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Just tested your code, and when I tried to resize a column by dragging the separator, a `StackOverFlowException` was thrown.

Comment: @ZhaoYi I did say it was hack.  I've made some bug fixes, should be working, better :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Can you post your newest code?

Comment: @ZhaoYi Yeah, I updated the linked question

Comment: @MadProgrammer: No exceptions are thrown this time but the table width can't be resized (by dragging the last separator in the header) to make the horizontal scroll bar appear.

Comment: @ZhaoYi So, as I understand it, you require it that the table be sized to fill the viewport when the table size is smaller the then viewport, but if the viewport is smaller the then the table, it will show the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Correct! In another word, the table width should never be smaller than the viewport width.

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried to set the minimal size as below but it didn't work:
>
> table.setMinimalSize(scrollPane.getSize());

- `JTable` and `JScrollPane` can't returns reasonable `Min`, `Max` and `PreferredSize`
- you can to fit (on applications startup) `JScrollPanes` dimension to JTable by using `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());` (carefully with number of row, otherwise you have to calculating a Dimension instead of JTable.getP...) for `JFrame.pack()`, on runtime must be validated by `revalidate()` and `repaint()` for container nested `JScrollPane`, don't do that
- don't reinvent the wheel, to use [Fixed Column Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/) of [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) by @camickr, which one isn't clear from your description,  depends of your ...

> a JTable's width >= the enclosing scroll pane's width?

- couldn't be reversed this idea