# Sizing a JTable

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable

EDIT: I know its posted as already answered but im having trouble with those solutions too.

I want a JTable that displays some SQL data in my application. I'm a beginner, but using the powers of google i've written the following code;

```
try
  {
      Statement st = ConnectionUtility.getConnection().createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT c.aname, c.telephone_number, c.address, "
              + "p.sku_code, p.appliance_type, p.colour, p.ticket_price " 
              + "FROM customers c " 
              + "INNER JOIN products p "
              + "ON c.sales_number = p.sales_number");

    JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));        
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {

  } 
}
```

The problem i have with this is the way the table looks.

[image: Jtable]

You see the columns aren't displaying all the data. How do I adjust the size of the table so that the columns display all the data?

I've tried using the following method from another question, but i still get the same result what I pass table through it. I'm probably being dumb, but what input would go in the argument for vColIndex & margin...

```
public static void packColumn(JTable table, int vColIndex, int margin) {
DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel)table.getColumnModel();
TableColumn col = colModel.getColumn(vColIndex);
int width = 0;

// Get width of column header
TableCellRenderer renderer = col.getHeaderRenderer();
if (renderer == null) {
    renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
}
java.awt.Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
    table, col.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
width = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

// Get maximum width of column data
for (int r=0; r<table.getRowCount(); r++) {
    renderer = table.getCellRenderer(r, vColIndex);
    comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        table, table.getValueAt(r, vColIndex), false, false, r, vColIndex);
    width = Math.max(width, comp.getPreferredSize().width);
}

// Add margin
width += 2*margin;

// Set the width
col.setPreferredWidth(width);
}
```

Ive also tried this from the same post... Still no luck

```
    JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
    for(int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++)
    {
        int width = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) 
        {
         TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, col);
         Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
         width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
        }     
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820238/how-to-resize-jtable-column-to-string-length/5820366

Comment: @copeg i must be being stupid, I cant get that to work, i just get the same result :(

Comment: @Khal Update your question with what you tried, because that's the answer (linked by copeg)

Comment: @MadProgrammerhave done so pal, still having a bit of trouble with this but i think im just not fully understanding it...